Adding Mention support in Apple Mail App using Apple's MailKit APIs
Is it possible to use the Apple MailKit API to add mention support to the Apple Mail app? Specifically, I’d like to be able to write “@deepak” and have my extension suggest email addresses starting with “deepak” from my contacts.
Currently, the Apple Mail app does not show suggestions when you tag or mention someone while drafting an email:

I was wondering if the MailKit API could be used to add this functionality. I noticed the MEComposeSessionHandler.viewController in the MailKit API, but according to the WWDC demo, it appears to only allow creating a UI in the toolbar section of the compose window.

Can someone with experience developing with Apple’s MailKit API confirm if this is possible or not?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
